# Jquery syntax error while implementing zoom hover plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-hover

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
        $('.my-gallery').imageZoom({
          $(this).imageZoom({
            zoom: 200
          });
        });
    });
});

HTML:
<link rel="stylesheet"href="{% static 'click-tap-image/dist/css/image-zoom.css' %}" />
<script src="{% static  'click-tap-image/dist/js/image-zoom.min.js' %}"></script>


      <div class="slider-for m-2" class="my-gallery">
        <img src="{% static 'images/product1.png' %}" width="80" class="gallery-image">
        <img src="{% static 'images/product2.png' %}" width="80" class="gallery-image">
        <img src="{% static 'images/product3.png' %}" width="80" class="gallery-image">
        <img src="{% static 'images/product4.png' %}" width="80" class="gallery-image">
        <img src="{% static 'images/product5.png' %}" width="80" class="gallery-image">
        <img src="{% static 'images/product3.png' %}" width="80" class="gallery-image">
      </div>
```

I linked the jquery click-image-[Error in js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqkMI.png)zoom plugin. what is the wrong with this code.. it shows an error in vscode showing '{' expected can someone please, help?

Comment: That is valid JQuery syntax. Therefore the issue is most likely somewhere else. Can you provide more code? Also `$(document).ready(function(){` & `$(function(){` does the same thing. I would suggest removing one of the lines and the closing `});`

Comment: I removed the $(document).ready line..still it shwoing error. I attached the error-image screenshot link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused on the line `$(this).imageZoom`. However you should not need this line as you're already calling `$('.my-gallery').imageZoom`. Simply just pass in the Zoom parameters

**For example:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.my-gallery').imageZoom({
        zoom: 200
    });
});
```